# creating a unique variable based on row differences of another variable considering groups

Tags: r, date, group-by, data.table, difference

By using the data below, I want to create a new unique customer id by considering their contact date.
Rule: After every two days, I want each customer to get a new unique customer id and preserve it on the following record if the following contact date for the same customer is within the following two days if not assign a new id to this same customer.

I couldn't go any further than calculating date differences.
The original dataset I work is bigger; therefore, I prefer a data.table solution if possible.

```
library(data.table)
treshold <- 2
dt <- structure(list(customer_id = c('10','20','20','20','20','20','30','30','30','30','30','40','50','50'),
                      contact_date = as.Date(c("2019-01-05","2019-01-01","2019-01-01","2019-01-02",
                                               "2019-01-08","2019-01-09","2019-02-02","2019-02-05",
                                               "2019-02-05","2019-02-09","2019-02-12","2019-02-01",
                                               "2019-02-01","2019-02-05")),
                      desired_output = c(1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,10)), 
                 class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = 1:14)
setDT(dt)
setorder(dt, customer_id, contact_date)
dt[, date_diff_in_days:=contact_date - shift(contact_date, type = c("lag")), by=customer_id]
dt[, date_diff_in_days:=as.numeric(date_diff_in_days)]
dt

    customer_id contact_date desired_output date_diff_in_days
 1:          10   2019-01-05              1                NA
 2:          20   2019-01-01              2                NA
 3:          20   2019-01-01              2                 0
 4:          20   2019-01-02              2                 1
 5:          20   2019-01-08              3                 6
 6:          20   2019-01-09              3                 1
 7:          30   2019-02-02              4                NA
 8:          30   2019-02-05              5                 3
 9:          30   2019-02-05              5                 0
10:          30   2019-02-09              6                 4
11:          30   2019-02-12              7                 3
12:          40   2019-02-01              8                NA
13:          50   2019-02-01              9                NA
14:          50   2019-02-05             10                 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use `cumsum` to increment whenever `date_diff_in_days` is `NA` or when the threshold is exceeded.

```
dt[, result := cumsum(is.na(date_diff_in_days) | date_diff_in_days > treshold)]
#     customer_id contact_date desired_output date_diff_in_days result
#  1:          10   2019-01-05              1                NA      1
#  2:          20   2019-01-01              2                NA      2
#  3:          20   2019-01-01              2                 0      2
#  4:          20   2019-01-02              2                 1      2
#  5:          20   2019-01-08              3                 6      3
#  6:          20   2019-01-09              3                 1      3
#  7:          30   2019-02-02              4                NA      4
#  8:          30   2019-02-05              5                 3      5
#  9:          30   2019-02-05              5                 0      5
# 10:          30   2019-02-09              6                 4      6
# 11:          30   2019-02-12              7                 3      7
# 12:          40   2019-02-01              8                NA      8
# 13:          50   2019-02-01              9                NA      9
# 14:          50   2019-02-05             10                 4     10
```

Answer (score 3):

> Rule: After every two days, I want each customer to get a new unique customer id and preserve it on the following record if the following contact date for the same customer is within the following two days if not assign a new id to this same customer.

When creating a new ID, if you set up the `by=` vectors correctly to capture the rule, the auto-counter `.GRP` can be used:

```
thresh <- 2
dt[, g := .GRP, by=.(
  customer_id, 
  cumsum(contact_date - shift(contact_date, fill=first(contact_date)) > thresh)
)]

dt[, any(g != desired_output)]
# [1] FALSE
```

I think the code above is correct since it works on the example, but you might want to check on your actual data (comparing against results from, eg, Gregor's approach) to be sure.